# Should I generate idea project with command line or should I import with the SBT plugin?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have had problems with openning project generated from build.sbt file. I prefer the command line approach because it seems more standard. But I got an error when compiling the project in IDE:

```
Error:scalac: Output path xxx is shared between: Module 'domainRegistrar-build' tests, Module 'domain_registrar-build' tests
......
```

Comment: That usually happens when idea finds two projects sharing some folder, to me it happened because I refactored the project and the IDE didn't pick up the changes, you can check in file -> project structure -> modules and then on the right under the sources label you should see the project structure, I can't tell you more because it's hard to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of this issues is two modules domainRegistrar-build and domain_registrar-build share same output path.

file -> project structure -> modules -> path

Change Output path to different one. (Normally it should add module name to distinguish the path)

Also, the two module names are similar, maybe you rename or manually create it, so refresh sbt project and rebuild project may be needed.

Answer (score -1):

update the scala-idea plugin in the plugins.sbt file. just like below:

```
resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")
```